# Appcelerator. Using factories but cannot access textfield values

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am developing an iOS app using appcelerator and I am trying to use JavaScript factories to seperate design (UI) from functions.

I made a component that shows a textfield in a fancy way (code located in ui.js). You can view the code here: http://pastie.org/2188537.

I then call the component like this on another page.

```
var desc = ambadooUI.createTextField({

    hinttext: 'Label (Personal/Work/Gmail...)',
    vertical: 10,
    container: 'top'

});
```

The problem is now that I cannot access the data/value of the textfield. How can I do it? Am I forced to use custom events?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the textField object as a property of the object you are returning.

for example at line 44, ui.js, you can do something like

```
// Return the finished button
top.text_field = textfield;
return top;
```